# Calculation of occurrence of strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns, id, name and vote. They're populated with many registers. I need that return the register with the best balance of votes. The votes types are 'yes' and 'no'.

Yes -> Plus 1 
No -> Minus 1

This column vote is a string column. I am using SQL SERVER.

Example:

[image]

It must return **Ann** for me

Comment: please show some sample data and expected result

Comment: Ok, 1 minute. I will put in the answer

Comment: if my answer or another worked for you please consider accepting it so others know you got what you needed and reputation points are assigned. thanks http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional Aggregation to tally the votes as Kannan suggests in his answer

If you really only want 1 record then you can do it like so:

```
SELECT TOP 1
   name
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN vote = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS VoteTotal
FROM
   @Table
GROUP BY
   name
ORDER BY
   VoteTotal DESC
```

This will not allow for ties but you can use this method which will rank the responses and give you results use RowNum to get only 1 result or RankNum to get ties.

```
;WITH cteVoteTotals AS (
    SELECT
       name
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN vote = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS VoteTotal
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY SUM(CASE WHEN vote = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) DESC) as RowNum
       ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY SUM(CASE WHEN vote = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) DESC) as RankNum
    FROM
       @Table
    GROUP BY
       name
)

SELECT name, VoteTotal
FROM
    cteVoteTotals
WHERE
    RowNum = 1
    --RankNum = 1  --if you want with ties use this line instead
```

Here is the test data used and in the future do NOT just put an image of your test data spend the 2 minutes to make a temp table or a table variable so that people you are asking for help do not have to!

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (id INT, name VARCHAR(25), vote VARCHAR(4))
INSERT INTO @Table (id, name, vote)
VALUES (1, 'John','no'),(2, 'John','no'),(3, 'John','yes')
,(4, 'Ann','no'),(5, 'Ann','yes'),(6, 'Ann','yes')
,(9, 'Marie','no'),(8, 'Marie','no'),(7, 'Marie','yes')
,(10, 'Matt','no'),(11, 'Matt','yes'),(12, 'Matt','yes')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

```
;with cte as (
select id, name, case when vote = 'yes' then 1 else -1 end as votenum from register
) select name, sum(votenum) from cte group by name
```

You can get max or minimum based out of this..

Comment: you don't need the cte you can just wrap the cast in SUM() but this also doesn't return the best record

Answer (score 0):

This one gives the 'yes' rate for each person:

```
SELECT Name, SUM(CASE WHEN Vote = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(*) AS Rate
FROM My_Table
GROUP BY Name
```